# (Unknown Source) in StackTrace with Tomcat7, Maven and Jensor Profiler

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, tomcat7, stack-trace

> **Related questions**
>
> [(Unknown Source) in Exception stack trace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3132302/1511277)
>
> [Unknown Source in Stacktrace Java Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16003525/1511277)

**My case**

I'm compiling a project using maven 3.1.0. Then it is deployed on Tomcat 7 On my stacktrace, I get (Unknown Source) instead of (myclass.java:14). It happens with my classes but works normally with others libraries.

From the related topics, I learn that it is due to missing line number in the class files. It may be due because the use of a jre or a wrong configuration. Here is some step I have tried:

- I recently moved from jdk 1.6 to  jdk1.7.0_21 (which looks to be the cause of the problem). I tried with three java installations (jdk1.7.0_21, 32 & 64bits and jdk1.7.0_45). JAVA_HOME is pointing to the right folder.
- I see that we can add debug and debuglevel option to javac. I tried to add them to maven with the following configuration. I also force to use javac instead of javax.

  ```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1</version>
          <configuration>
              <source>${jdk.version}</source>
              <target>${jdk.version}</target>
              <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel>
              <debug>true</debug>
              <forceJavacCompilerUse>true</forceJavacCompilerUse>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  ```
- Erase target file and tomcat war.

Nothing works...

**EDIT**
Using `javap -l` on the class shows the LineNumberTable:

```
public void init();
  LineNumberTable:
    line 31: 0
    line 32: 10
    line 33: 21
    ...
```

The problem comes most likely from the tomcat7 side.

Comment: You can try checking the compiled `.class` files using `javap`. Although unlikely, it may be possible that the lines are there but Tomcat does something shifty while loading them. You can also create a completely new project with a single test java file and your compiler options in the POM, just to help you simplify the task.

Comment: Run `mvn -X compile` to see what is maven actually doing. Run `mvn help:effective-pom` to see the final maven configuration.

Comment: @biziclop Ok that strange `javap -l` shows the LineNumberTable. I will look in the tomcat side

Comment: It must be some VM optimisation flag or similar in Tomcat then.

Comment: Not yet. I didn't find anything interesting on the side of tomcat or VM. I should go for a simple test case but I hadn't the time yet. But I think it's strange that the problem comes from tomcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was coming from the JVM.

I use Jensor for profiling my application. It uses Aspect and a javaagent in order to collect data.

By removing the `-javaagent:...` from the java options solved the problem.